# Merge wrath-of-the-lamb into binding-of-isaac?

Tags: discussion, tags

In light of recent decisions about the tagging of expansions, is there any reason why we shouldn't merge [wrath-of-the-lamb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wrath-of-the-lamb) into [binding-of-isaac](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binding-of-isaac)?

In particular, I'm looking for:

- Questions that were answered with just the expansion in mind but could also apply to the base version, and the answer then is different
- Questions that were asked both for the expansion and the base version with different answers
- Any other reason why we shouldn't do it.

I'm asking before I do the merge because the merge would change the 57 questions involved retroactively (no bumping, no entry in revision history).

> WOtL questions, from newest to oldest; those that might give trouble are in italics:
>
> [soul hearts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161477/do-soul-hearts-count-as-tribute-hearts), [curse of darkness](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95768/does-buying-the-treasure-map-cancel-the-curse-of-darkness-curse), [challenges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95587/what-counts-as-beating-a-challenge-in-binding-of-isaac), [buying](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95121/is-wrath-of-the-lamb-available-to-buy-anywhere-besides-steam), [sacrificial dagger](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85792/is-the-sacrificial-dagger-like-the-other-orbitals), [Isaac](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85601/what-strategy-can-i-use-to-beat-isaac), *[no damage achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77694/what-counts-as-damage-for-the-no-damage-achievements)*, *[secret rooms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/76790/how-do-secret-rooms-work-in-wrath-of-the-lamb)*, [platinum god](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75577/are-the-chest-level-unlockables-required-for-platinum-god), *[bad pills](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/74211/why-did-my-pills-change)*, [challenges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73920/do-challenge-runs-count-towards-isaacs-completion-achievements), *[Ankh and achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73803/if-i-use-the-ankh-and-manage-to-kill-the-final-boss-who-gets-credit-for-the-kil)*, *[secret rooms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73198/what-are-all-of-the-rules-that-determine-where-secret-rooms-appear)*, *[secret rooms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73142/how-can-i-find-the-secret-rooms-most-efficiently)*, *[golden/platinum god](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73020/are-the-no-damage-achievements-necessary-to-get-golden-god-and-platinum-god)*, [soul hearts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72795/what-happens-if-i-get-an-eternal-heart-when-i-already-have-12-heart-containers), [scrapular](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72665/how-does-the-scapular-work), [golden god](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72640/is-the-golden-god-achievement-still-possible-with-wrath-of-the-lamb), [cathedral](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72187/how-do-i-unlock-the-cathedral-in-the-wrath-of-the-lamb-dlc), *[blood lust](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72085/can-blood-lust-take-me-above-max-damage)*, [Sheol](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71767/are-sheol-achievements-locked-now-with-wrath-of-the-lamb), [hidden rooms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71625/how-does-the-new-type-of-secret-room-work), *[Samson](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71278/can-i-unlock-samson-by-ignoring-two-treasure-rooms-on-the-same-floor)*, *[heart drop rates](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71061/how-does-the-game-prioritize-hearts)*, [trinkets](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71059/which-trinkets-are-available-in-wrath-of-the-lamb), [cellar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71045/why-my-cellar-changed-and-now-is-full-of-spider-webs), [alternate levels](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70989/can-i-choose-which-level-ill-go-in), [Isaac](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70943/what-do-you-have-to-do-to-fight-isaac), *[title screen puzzle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70942/what-happens-if-i-complete-the-title-screen-puzzle)*, [alternative slot machine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70829/what-does-the-fortune-telling-slot-machine-do), [A missing page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70814/what-does-the-a-missing-page-trinket-do), [challenges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70797/what-are-each-of-the-challenges), [boss duel rooms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70778/how-do-the-new-skull-challenge-rooms-work), [curses](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70777/how-many-curses-have-been-introduced-in-wrath-of-the-lamb-and-what-is-their-ef), [orange fire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70772/whats-the-difference-between-yellow-and-orange-fire), *[luck stat](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70752/what-is-the-stat-luck)*, [alternate levels](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70747/what-are-all-the-levels-introduced-in-wrath-of-the-lamb), [Undefined](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70738/what-does-the-undefined-fish-head-trinket-do), [changes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70736/how-does-wrath-of-the-lamb-change-the-binding-of-isaac), [Spirit of the Night](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70735/what-does-spirit-of-the-night-do), [flies orbiting poop](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70733/what-is-the-deal-with-this-weird-poop-and-white-fly), [portable slots](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70732/are-the-chances-between-the-portable-slots-and-the-slot-machine-different), *[orange keys](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70728/what-do-the-orange-keys-do)*, [trinkets](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70722/i-found-an-item-and-it-went-to-a-weird-spot-on-my-screen-now-what), [bloody lust](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70719/what-does-bloody-lust-do), [Chemical peel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70718/do-normal-tears-do-increased-damage-with-chemical-peel), [Child's heart](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70717/what-does-the-childs-heart-do), [teethed doors](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/why-does-this-door-have-teeth), *[Samson](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70708/what-counts-as-passing-on-a-treasure-room)*, [sacrifice rooms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70705/is-there-anything-special-about-the-blood-rooms), [red chests](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70703/whats-different-about-red-chests), [soul hearts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70701/what-are-the-white-hearts), [soul hearts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70700/what-does-fate-do), [Mitre](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70699/what-does-the-mitre-do), *[secret rooms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45530/which-walls-are-bombable)*.

Comment: What decisions are you referring to?

Comment: @shanodin The Diablo 3 expansion not having its own tag. I have not taken part in these discussions myself - hence the asking - but I've seen references to [what happened to Starcraft 2](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/4740/23).

Answer (score 2):

### Keep the tags separate.

It's still possible (and legal) to get and play a copy of The Binding of Issac without the expansion.

With the Blizzard games you've mentioned, patches to the base game have changed the mechanics so that they are aligned with the expansion. All you get from buying the expansion is new content. Conversely, if any mechanics changes were brought about by WotL, these would not be applied to people only playing the base game.

Comment: +1 for identifying the specific reason that Blizzard Games Are Exceptional in this regard.